# In my opencart site i need to play a video in home page before opening my site

Tags: opencart

I need to play a video in my opencart site before opening the site home page.is there any extension or jquery is available to perform this function?

Answer (score 0):

For this no need to the opencart extensions, you may create with the following two options.

1. create one simple html with video and set us a index.html and give one link from this page to site home page.
2. load one simple popup with video at the time of page load.